Attempting to authenticate Firebase tells me I first need to authenticate Firebase. Huh?
I am using Firebase.  I am getting the error:

Error: Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid. Please run firebase login --reauth

I have tried running firebase login --reauth, but it just gives me the exact same error.  I also get the same error running firebase logout, firebase deploy, firebase login:ci, firebase init, and firebase --reauth --no-localhost. (Any firebase command just tells me to reauth, including the reauth command.)
I have tried:

Restarting my computer
Uninstalling and reinstalling firebase tools
Clearing the firebase cache via npm cache clean --force in the npm folder
Deleting and recloning the repository
Deleting .firebaserc and firebase.json

How can I fix my Firebase?

I am getting exactly the same error this morning. firebase --version 13.13.2

Downgraded to 13.13.1, then it worked for me.

Firebaser here:
The root cause of this was an issue where firebase-tools used refresh tokens before checking if they were expired. It has been fixed in 13.13.3, so please upgrade when you have a chance.

Firebase version 13.13.2 is broken.  Downgrade:
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
npm install -g firebase-tools@13.13.1
firebase login --reauth

